# How can define a custom price based on other product attributes Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am working on a webshop where the products are tires (car tires)

I've deciced to go with Laravel as PHP framework.

I want to return a price in my model, the price is not static but is based on other values in the model. (the thickness of the weel)

How can I make a function in my controller or model which checks for other values for the specific tire.

I think I should make it in the model or controller but don't know how to do this.

Comment: You have to tell us more. At least your database structure and how is the price calculated.

Comment: The database structure id, brand, model, thickness

Comment: The thickness is for example 15-20

Comment: The price is if between 15 and 20 the price is 50

Comment: Where are the prices stored?

Comment: In the code with if and elses based on the thickness of the tire

Comment: Maybe it's a idea to just store the price and just update all tires when something changed

Comment: Hardcoding the price in the model is a horrible idea. You should store it in the database, and associate it properly with the product attribute.

Comment: @Bogdan I know that I'll think about another solution!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose one way of doing would be the following:

App\Models\Tires.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Tires;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tires extends Model {

    protected $connection = 'mysql';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'tires';

    protected $fillable = array(
        'brand',
        'model',
        'thickness,
        'price'
    );

    public $timestamps = true;

}
```

App\Http\Controllers\TiresController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Tires;
use App\Functions\CalcTires;

class TiresController extends Controller
{

    public function customPrice()
    {
        $findtires = Tires::all();

        foreach ($findtires as $_findtires)
        {
            $calcprice = new CalcTires($_findtires->thickness);
            $_findtires->price = $calcprice->getCustomPrice();
            $_findtires->save();
        }
    }

}
```

App\Models\Functions\CalcTires.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Functions;

class CalcTires {

    var $price;

    function __construct($thickness) {

        if ($thickness >= 15 && $thickness <= 20)
        {
            $this->price = 50;
        }
        elseif ($thickness >= 21 && $thickness <= 25)
        {
            $this->price = 60;
        }
    }

    function getCustomPrice() {
        return $this->price;
    }

}
```

This is adding an extra "Price" column to your table model and also utilizing a function to do the price calculation and lastly saving it back to your database.

Of course you could always pre-calculate all this yourself and save yourself the trouble before importing the data into your database.